# Puzzling behavior for op-amp driven MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, source-follower

Consider this circuit:

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DOheCBEeINUKzJtacvs8xsASo77PJ7Hu/view) (Ctrl+S on the text view)

[image]

As you can see, the positive input, \$V_{IN1}\$, of the op-amp is floating & yet, it will exhibit the following behavior:

- Just like a voltage follower, it will cause the NMOS to output 8V on the \$R_{LOAD}\$ for a very wide resistance values. Why 8V in this example, exactly? Seems to be dependent on \$V_{DD}\$.
- Because of the voltage follower above, the feedback voltage at \$V_{IN2}\$ is \$\frac{V_{LOAD}R_1}{R1 + R2}\$, or 4V in the example. I've just convinced myself that opamps just hits the proper output so it's 2 inputs equal each other, but here I see it balancing at 4V, even if I were to put a different constant voltage at \$V_{IN1}\$. \$\quad V_{IN1}\$ is basically being ignored.

The reason for my inquiry is perhaps some quirky mechanism is a play that I can exploit. As I am still working on linearly driving MOSFETs or IGBTs using op-amps.

Comment: You can't expect meaningful behavior if you leave the inout open-circuit. The actual behavior could be explained but will vary with the type of opamp.

Comment: I'm just dilly dallying right now. So I decided to post this.

Comment: Opamps are a mess. All the little features that were added to make it behave a certain way, but never labelled as such. Then there's the internals to get the fundamentals working.

Comment: I'm still leaning at parallelizing it. My gut tells me there's a way & history shows that my gut has been more right than wrong.

Comment: Well in this case it's wrong because it's meaningless since you don't even have a real opamp specified eliminating even the small possibility of simulating real quirks or undefined behaviour . Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Are you using `UniversalOpamp2` ?  If so, did you just use the default parameters or did you tweak them?

Comment: @Ste I have a bad habit of only tinkering what I need to know for the moment. So even if I have an inkling what \$A_o\$, slew rate, gain-bandwidth, etc are, I don't touch them almost at all. I don't like designing around some fancy or high-end property of a specific component. Everything has to be stock. When I'm stress testing it then, sure, I'll touch the parameters. Gotta pick up simulation at some point someday...

Comment: OK, so "yes" to the first question.  "no" to the second.  Got it.

Comment: "Gotta pick up [noise] simulation at some point someday..."

Answer (score 3):

It's an artifact of the opamp SPICE model and/or the simulator.

If the opamp has a MOS input device, then the 'floating' gate voltage is not well defined in SPICE. A more detailed opamp model may include ESD protection circuit which could possibly bias the pin to 4 V. A transient analysis may start the supplies (and input) at 0 V, and then G-D and G-S capacitive division may define (for SPICE) an input voltage.

Rail-rail bipolar input opamps may tend to drive inputs pins to some known voltage when left floating.

You cannot depend on any of these results in a physical prototype and will not be able to actually measure the '4 V' on the pin.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things going on here.  First, if you leave an input on `UniversalOpamp2` floating, it will approach half of the difference between V+ and V-.  In this case it will be 6V.  This is because if you look at `Documents\LTspiceXVII\lib\sub\UniversalOpAmp2.lib`, you'll see that the `Rin` parameter gets split evenly between each rail, forming an even voltage divider.  So half of 12V-0V is 6V.  The value of `Rin` defaults to 500Meg, but in this instance it doesn't matter since the node is fully floating.  The value would matter if you hooked up something with megs or gigs of impedance to the input or used the command `.options gshunt=x`.

Second, the LTspice built-in IRF530 model has a `Vto` (zero-bias threshold voltage) of 4V.  So the lowest voltage you can support at the output is 12V-4V = 8V.

Lastly, you don't have a follower you have a gain of 2 non-inverting amplifier.  So any voltage at the (+) terminal would be multiplied by two and added by 4V (to compensate for the threshold voltage described above).  Therefore, your opamp circuit saturates at an input of 4V or higher.  Since your floating input is at 6V, it also saturates the opamp.  Remove R1 to get more range of valid input voltages.

Answer (score -2):

It's fairly obvious that the floating input will approach the 12V Vdd, and the output will then be at its maximum output, probably close to 12V. The typical gate threshold voltage of the [IRF530](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91019/irf530.pdf) is 3V, so meaningful conduction will occur at about 4V, so the voltage on the load from the source would be 12-4 = 8V.

Comment: \$V_{th} = 4V\$. I know, right? So I suspected something must be going on that I could exploit. Turns out it's just a chance of numbers being the same as Numerology itself.